# Want to access Spring Boot Service without port in URL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

For example

https://192.168.1.136:8081/ works fine

But if I try to access

https://192.168.1.136/ Error - The site can't be reached.

What are the ways to access it without a port in **URL**?

Comment: You need NGNIX or Apache HTTP server as a proxy server for forwarding HTTP requests to appropriate application -> which listens a particular port.

Comment: Is any example available? and would it work on MAC?

Comment: this may help: https://gist.github.com/natchiketa/987524a561e892924e81

Comment: This would work with Spring boot and its embedded tomcat?

Comment: Yes, it should work.

Comment: It is working. But not with https. If I do http://192.168.1.136/ it works but if I do https://192.168.1.136/  it doesn't coz I think it hot 443 port

Answer (score 0):

Assign port 80 instead of 8081 will work.

Update `application.properties` in `/src/main/resources/` with

`server.port=80`

Alternatively you may also set `server.port` as system property using command line option to jvm `-Dserver.port=80`

Comment: @GunjanDave port 80 works with and without port as its default port and for port setting mentioned two options works. I will say please cross check once might be something is missing there. Otherwise please elaborate specific issue are you not able to assign port 80 or assigning 80 too not working?

Comment: Assigning port 80 works. But I don't want to assign port 80. I want port 8081 and also want to access URL without a port

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I got your requirement you need reverse proxy please have look into reverse proxy there are some provided and some you may customize.

Provided are : haproxy and others.
Customizable are zuul (https://github.com/ravindra-yadava/rproxy)